# Parsing divs with same class individually?

Tags: php, domparser

I have divs with same Class value;

```
<div class="description">Div 1</div>
<div class="description">Div 2</div>
<div class="description">Div 3</div>
```

and I can parse and display them all with this code:

```
foreach($html->find('.description') as $icerik) { echo '<b>'.$icerik->plaintext.'</b>'; }
```

Now I want to display them individually. How to make them parse and display like first div, second div and third div?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide required output

Comment: I'm not positive, but would `$html->find('.description')[0]->plaintext` work? It's referred to as [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) implemented in 5.4.

Comment: Doesn't work.

"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ..."

Comment: Ah, well the following works with DOMXPath (just tested): `$html->query("//*[@class='description']")->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$html->find('.description')` returns an array of dom node objects you might put the result in a variable in which you could access them directly.

```
$description_divs = $html->find('.description');
echo 'first div '.$description_divs[0]->plaintext.'<br><br>';
echo 'second div '.$description_divs[1]->plaintext.'<br><br>';
echo 'third div '.$description_divs[2]->plaintext.'<br><br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
foreach($html->find('.description') as $icerik) {
    echo '<div><b>'.$icerik->plaintext.'</b></div>';
}
```